# How to hide or disable "allow PC to be discoverable on this network"?

Tags: windows, networking, security

How to always hide or disable "allow PC to be discoverable on this network"? I've created a scheduled task to take care of that which means this prompt is not only unnecessary it's also a security risk if accidentally clicked.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Nr2.jpg]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to prevent this dialog from showing by adding the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff
```

Open `regedit.exe`, navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network`, and add a new key by the name of `NewNetworkWindowOff`.

[image: Animated screen recording]

From: https://serverfault.com/questions/634982/how-to-avoid-the-prompt-do-you-want-to-find-pcs-devices-and-content, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252535(v=ws.10).aspx